# there is no process diagram generated when activiti6 dynamic deploy

Tags: java, activiti

When I was using `Activiti6.0`, I found that:

- When the project path `BPMN file is deployed`, two data files are inserted into the ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY table, one an XML file and the other an automatically generated image file.

[image]

- However, when using `dynamically deployed BpmnModel classes`, the ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY table inserts only one XML file instead of a corresponding image file.

[image]

Anybody know why

here is the source code of dynamic deploy process:

```
BpmnModel model = new BpmnModel();
Process process = new Process();
model.addProcess(process);
process.setId("news");
///~ init process...
Deployment deployment = activitiRule.getRepositoryService()
            .createDeployment()
            .addBpmnModel(process.getId() + ".bpmn", model)
            .name(process.getName() + "_deployment")
            .deploy();
```